# SVN check in /commit error

Tags: svn, commit

I had checked out a few files from the svn repository on an old machine, and then I moved the repository to a new server. I did not do a repo dump and move, just did a tar and scp and untar of the entire repository. When I try to check in to the new server [with the same hostname and same dir structure] it says:

> svn: Commit failed (details follow):
>   svn: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to MKACTIVITY request for '/repos/papers/!svn/act/a49a699c-96a7-11df-9e8f-654930a0ec4e'

Comment: If you still have access to the old machine, compare the subversion versions of both and update your post. We might be able to help a lot better that way.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you move or backup a SVN Repo, you need to do a dump and then restore on the new machine.  You can accomplish that by running:

> svnadmin dump myrepos > dumpfile

Then move the `dumpfile` onto the new machine using your transport tool of choice.  Once on the new server:

> svnadmin load newrepos < dumpfile

On your working copy, you will need to inform your svn client that the repo has moved.

Answer (score 0):

Check your error log to dig deep into this issue. I suspect the issue is with your apache LoadModule configuration or with Authentication.

Comment: AFAIK, the server won't even start if there is a problem with loading modules. On authentication related error, you'll see another error.